# How after update the database in the Servlet and press many times the refresh button in the browser, i DONT can see the old entries?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, entity

In my Servlet i update the user details via Entity Manager and JDBC and if i go to "My Profile" AFTER the update, i have there a table with all the data inside. The update every time is successfull, but if i press many times the refresh button, after every 7-10 clicks i can see in the table the OLD entries 1 time and then after the next click the new data... ( in the mysql workbench i can see that tha data successfull updated ). I have a JSP page where i have a table with the users data ( read only attribute in the HTML code ) and if the user presses edit, i send the data via GET method to a new JSP Page where i can edit all the data in a form. Then i can press Save and the update is done. Any idea how i can fix this little bug ?

Comment: Can you share your code snippets? Also, give more details regarding your question as it is not clear from what you have mentioned.

Comment: the code is to huge ... I think the problem is in the caching of the tomcat that i use. For example : i update username: Josh   to:   username: Mike. I go to the "My Profile" and in the start i can see: username: Mike. After 7-10 times fast click on the refresh button, i can see : username:Josh again... But in the mysql workbench i can see that the username changed successfull... I am more searching for the reason and not for any code ...

Comment: You may want to look at https://serverfault.com/q/40205/435497.

Comment: I saw this but this don't helped me ... I don't wanna change the tomcat caching settings ...

Comment: Is it possible to setup anything in Tomcat, so that after every update, the cache gonna be updated or something like this ? i think in the cache are the old database entries and there is the problem ...

Comment: I think what you are saying makes sense. But not sure how to clear cache on each update.